# How can I run multi-stage Azure DevOps pipelines from beginning to end without other runs getting interleaved?

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

Let me explain...  I have a multi-stage pipeline with 2 stages.  If I do a commit to master, a CI run for that pipeline is triggered (Run.A).  Then, if I immediately make a change and commit to master again, another run of that pipeline will get triggered (Run.B).  So far, so good.  However, here's the order in which the runs and stages subsequently execute:

- RunA.Stage.1, RunB.Stage1, RunA.Stage.2, RunB.Stage2

What I want is...

- RunA.Stage.1, RunA.Stage2, RunB.Stage.1, RunB.Stage2

Is there a way to accomplish this?